# How do I make cards of different heights fill gap in css?

Tags: css, material-design, flexbox

I would like to create a group of cards of varying height, but I have had trouble displaying them  so that it does not have extra space below the shorter ones.

I want it to look like this:

[image]

What I *do not* want is to have the cards stretch to fill the space.
I want the card below to slide up to fill the space.

Is this possible with pure CSS? If not, how would I do this with Javascript?

Here's something to work with:
http://codepen.io/calebeby/pen/LGaVoL

```
.row {
    @include display(flex);
    @include flex-wrap(wrap);
}
```

Comment: One way you can do is to create two columns and put the cards inside each columns. That way with only css, html you can solve the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to adopt 'Masonry - Cascading grid layout library' js for creating these type layouts.

[Masonry Cascading Grid Layout](http://masonry.desandro.com/)
[Masonry Cascading Grid Layout - Options](http://masonry.desandro.com/options.html)